# Copy Data from Database1 Mysql TableA to Database2 Mysql TableA with Ado.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ado.net, dataadapter

The transfer of data from one database to another with the Entitiy Framework doesn't seem to be simple. So i have another try with datatables & dataadapters:

```
    MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    string query2 = "SELECT * FROM `" + targetTable + "`";
    command.CommandText = query2;
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

    DataTable tableToUpdate = new DataTable("myTable");
    dataAdapter.FillSchema(tableToUpdate, SchemaType.Source);
    dataAdapter.Fill(tableToUpdate);

    // an den DataAdapter übergeben
    MySqlCommandBuilder myComBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myComBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = myComBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

    tableToUpdate.Merge(sourceDT,false);

    int changeCount = dataAdapter.Update(tableToUpdate);s
    DataTable changes = tableToUpdate.GetChanges();
```

the update and insert commands seem to be right, but nothing is updated in the database?

edit:
The problem seems to be in the merging of the dataTables. New columns aren't added. New Rows are added but the Rowstate is Unchanged.

Comment: Possibly silly, but I see no tableToUpdate.AcceptChanges()

Comment: that is not the solution